# How to avoid multiple click on ListView?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, expandablelistview

In my application I have `ListView`. OnClick of each row in `ListView` I displayed an `AlertDialog`. The problem is that, when I click multiple times  on `ListView` row it shows `AlertDialog` multiple times? But I want to display an `AlertDialog` only one time.

Comment: use `boolean` variable for single click .....

Comment: Can you paste your code segment here?

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of AlertDialog globally and show alert only if it is not showing.

Like this -

```
if(mMyDialog.isShowing()) {
   mMyDialog.show();
}
```